# undefined reference to `` с++

Tags: c++, c, jni

Продолжая изучать тему нативных библиотек Java при попытке вызвать метод с++ из с получаю ошибку сборки:

```
CMakeFiles\Cpart.dir/objects.a(tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.c.obj): In 
function `Java_tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper_voidMethod': D:/WORKSPACE/Intellij_Idea/NoAsm/NativeLibraryTest+HowTo/Cpart/tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.c:5: undefined reference to `voidMethod'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [libCpart.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Cpart.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Cpart.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Cpart.dir\build.make:123: recipe for target 'libCpart.dll' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Cpart] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Cpart.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Cpart.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Cpart' failed
```

С с и с++ настолько не силен (проходили первые пол курса университета и такое соотв. не изучали)
В чем моя ошибка, можно пожалуйста более-менее подробно ?

файлы :

tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper */

#ifndef _Included_tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper
#define _Included_tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper    
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper_voidMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.c:

```
#include "tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.h"
#include "NativeLibraryImplementation.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper_voidMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
voidMethod(env,obj);

}
```

NativeLibraryImplementation.h :

```
#ifndef CPART_NATIVELIBRARYIMPLEMENTATION_H
#define CPART_NATIVELIBRARYIMPLEMENTATION_H

#include <jni.h>

void voidMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#endif //CPART_NATIVELIBRARYIMPLEMENTATION_H
```

NativeLibraryImplementation.cpp :

```
#include "NativeLibraryImplementation.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void voidMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
cout << "native void method output\n";
}
```

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Cpart)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories("$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include" "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/win32")

set(SOURCE_FILES tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.h tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.c NativeLibraryImplementation.h NativeLibraryImplementation.cpp)

add_library(Cpart SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: g++ это опечатка?

Comment: В Clion в Toolchains напротив C++Compiller написано так : D:programs\mingw64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe        напротив C Compiller так : D:programs\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe     Я думаю что может это связано с компилятором или сборщиком

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `с++` код на `с` код, и переименовать файл. Возможно, дело в декорировании имен.

Comment: @alexolut сработало, а не подскажете что это за декорирование и как все таки перейти от с к с++?

Comment: В оригинале это называется `name mangling`, и нужно из-за возможности перегрузок (одинаковых имён) функций в `c++`. В `с` перегрузок нет и имена не декорируются. Посмотрите ещё про `extern "c"` для функций, должно помочь.

Comment: @alexolut, Спасибо.             
 #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 в заголовочном файле cpp-шника (++ части) помогло

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка компилятора говорит вам о том, что при линковке не видно тела функции voidMethod.
Сам код верен. Дело действительно в настройках компилятора и линковщика.
cmake рекомендую чуть изменить, вот так

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Cpart)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY})

set(SOURCE_FILES 
    tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.h 
    tr1nks_NativeLibraryWrapper.c 
    NativeLibraryImplementation.h 
    NativeLibraryImplementation.cpp)

add_library(Cpart SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: С вашим вариантом cmake ошибка осталась. А в чем может быть проблема, почему линковщик не видит тело ф-ии ??

Comment: 1.Проверьте правильность путей к средствам сборки
2. Проверьте разрядность jdk и сборки gcc (т.е. если jdk-64, а gcc-32, то не гуд)
3. Посмотрите пример тут http://www.mingw.org/wiki/JNI_MinGW_DLL

Comment: в настройках Clion так: [изображение](https://goo.gl/Fys23Y), все х64 кроме make, он такой какой поставился комплектом

Comment: Кроме того когда я переношу реализацию метода с++ в .h файл все собирается и работает, но так не правильно, в заголовке должен быть заголовок

Comment: все верно, в заголовке должен быть прототип.
Изображение не открывается.
...
Чтобы понять что не так, надо знать как должно быть, в общем должно быть так... Для каждого c и cpp файла компилятор должен создать объектный файл .o , затем линковщик берет эти файлы и пытается найти тела всех функций, адреса которых попали в объектники, если чего-то нет, то мы получаем Вашу ошибку, поэтому, проверьте, что для каждого cppшника создался объектник