# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries - iostream

Tags: java, c++, jni

Продолжая исследовать JNI столкнулся с таким моментом: в файлах в которых я описываю реализацию методов(cpp), при подключении `iostream` после сборки библиотеки (которая проходит нормально) в ходе выполнения java при попытке загрузить либу ловлю `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries`
Опытным путем выяснил что это `iostream` (убираю его и все работает).

Вопрос такой, это ограничение связанное с потоками вывода (java как то это дело блокирует или контролирует) или есть какая то хитрость ?

проблемный код:

```
//#include <iostream>// как только подключаю - ошибка 
#include <windows.h>// для проверки того что другие либы импортятся
#include <conio.h>// для проверки того что другие либы импортятся
#include "implementation.h"


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL voidMethod_impl(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
printf("%s", "printf test");
//    std::cout<<"test cout\n";// даже если это закомментировано а iostream подключен - всеравно ошибка
}
```

Comment: Покажите как компилируете.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, С помощью CLion, конфиг CMakeLists.txt такой как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706574/undefined-reference-to-с) я указывал (за исключением других имен моих файлов)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev собрал вручную, но проблема осталась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что по умолчанию gcc линкует вашу dll'ку динамически с библиотеками libgcc, libstdc++ и libwinpthread. Соответственно, есть несколько способов ошибку не получать.

Во-первых, можно положить dll'ки этих библиотек в каталог присутствующий в переменной окружения PATH.

Во-вторых, при запуске программы передать JVM параметр `java.library.path`, содержащий пути как к вашей dll'ке, так и к dll'кам необходимых библиотек:

```
java -Djava.library.path=.;D:\PROGRAMS\mingw64_7_1\bin com.example.Main
```

В-третьих, можно слинковать эти библиотеки с вашей статически. Самый простой способ - передать компилятору параметр `-static`, но тогда он запихнёт в вашу dll'ку всё, что ему покажется необходимым.

Или можно явно указать, какие библиотеки необходимы:

```
g++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias ^
-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" ^
-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" ^
-L"%MINGW_HOME%\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" ^
-shared -o example.dll Example.cpp ^
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ ^
-Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread
```

Comment: Если сделать static то ошибка : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\WORKSPACE\Intellij_Idea\NoAsm\NativeLibTest_instruction\out\production\res\lib\libc.dll: %1 не является приложением Win32, а указать все библиотеки - помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: Это странно. Похоже, что у вас libc или битая или другой разрядности.

Comment: libc это та самая либа в которую я все собираю и она х64

Answer (score 0):

Нет, Java ничего не блокирует. Просто вам нужно явно указать путь до внешней библиотеки (в вашем случае, iostream) используя:

```
-Djava.library.path="<path_to_lib>"
```

PS. В дополнение, можете посмотреть подобные вопросы и варианты их решения:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783632/how-do-i-load-and-use-native-library-in-java

Comment: java -Djava.library.path="D:\PROGRAMS\mingw64_7_1\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.1.0\include\c++\iostream" -jar NativeLibTest_instruction.jar     - не помогло ( та же ошибка